# Unexpected value of Google PageSpeed insights API when used with Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, pagespeed

I'm using the PageSpeed API to pull data using Google Script into Google Sheets.

However, when I execute the script and fetch data from the PageSpeed URL, the time-to-first-byte numeric value is substantially higher than when I run it in my regular browser window.

For example, when I fetch the URL within Google Sheets with the code below, my average Time-to-first-byte is 500-510ms. While if I use the exact same URL in chrome on my desktop, it's generally 60-70ms.

This is the code I use to pull in the data:

```
    function callPageSpeed(strategy) {
  var pageSpeedUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=' + pageSpeedMonitorUrl + '&key=' + pageSpeedApiKey + '&strategy=' + strategy;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pageSpeedUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json);}
```

I then push it into my sheet using:

```
function monitor() {      
var desktop = callPageSpeed('desktop');
  var mobile = callPageSpeed('mobile');
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('results');
  sheet.appendRow([
                   Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+1', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                   desktop['lighthouseResult']['audits']['time-to-first-byte']['numericValue'].toFixed(0) + " ms"
//some other metrics go here
                  ]);
```

Does anybody know what might cause this, and how I can overcome it?

Comment: no reason it would be different, my guess is you are accidentally breaking the URL so it isn't running the desktop version and it is so similar you aren't noticing, try logging the url it outputs and directly copying it to check there isn't some weird encoding issue going on (turning `&` into `%26` for example).

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the time average between your direct Browser execution call and the one in your Apps Script execution is due to Apps Script code runs in Google's servers and not in your local machine as the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) say:

> There's nothing to install—we give you a code editor right in your
>   browser, and your scripts run on Google's servers.

Take that into consideration when calling external APIs because it can have other side effects, besides time average differences like having an IP address that you can't assign.